# Synonym request [lexer] -> [lexical-analysis]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

There are two tags about lexical analysers; there were more ([lexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexing) & [lexical-scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-scanner)), but those have either been edited out or synonymised in the past.

We are now left with [lexical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analysis) ([574 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analysis)) and [lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexer) ([587 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexer)).

The tag [lexical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analysis) already has synonyms of [lexical-analyser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analyser) and [lexical-analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analyzer) whereas [lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexer) has no synonyms.

It seems to make sense to map [lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexer) to [lexical-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lexical-analysis). There are too many questions for any sensible manual tag edits.

Comment: But are those really synonyms?

Comment: @rene Yes; they have been used indiscriminately for the same thing; the process of lexing or the analyser that performs that process.

Comment: Title suggestion: `If [lexer]s do [lexical-analysis], then why not synonymize the tags?`